# Viewing different planes from DICOM image slices

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, 3d, dicom

I have a 3D DICOM data (slices) and I need to display the three planes (axial, sagittal and coronal) from that data.
I read all the slices in MATLAB and used that 3D matrix as follows.

```
Axial = dicomMatrix(:, :, zIndex);
Sagittal = dicomMatrix(xIndex, :, :)
Coronal = dicomMatrix(:, yIndex, :)
```

But when I display the above images the sagittal and coronal planes seems like exchanged.
What am I doing wrong?

As far as my understanding, the orientation of DICOM images are, L->R, A->P & I->S
Therefore I considered that X is increasing to R, Y is increasing to P and Z is increasing to S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the first dimension in MATLAB is y (rows) and the second is x (columns), not the other way around.  See [Matrix Indexing in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html).